# Altering an array passed from another method

Tags: arrays

Basic question. If i have the two following methods:

```
public sendArray []int(){
 []int myArray = new int[5];
 //do stuff to myArray.
return myArray
}

public alterArray{
sendArray();

//How to access myArray now?
}
```

In the method alterArray how do i access and alter the myArray once sendArray has been called?

Answer (score 0):

assign the output of function to a new array:

```
public alterArray{
[]int newArray =sendArray();
}
```